# using string as a condition in LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

Consider i have the following linq query.I want to specify the condition in where clause as a string as i will make it empty when i wont have any condition.But on doing so i am getting the error :
"**Cant explitily convert string to bool**".I know the reason for the error.I just want to know is there any other alternative to implement the following.

```
var elements = from element in array
               orderby element descending
               where element > 2
               select element;
```

**string condition="element >"+2;**

I want to do the following....

```
var elements = from element in array
               orderby element descending
               where condition<------------            
                           select element;
```

**PS:I will handle the situation when there is no condition and the where clause is left with no condition.**

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Use DynamicLinq (http://dynamiclinq.codeplex.com/).

Answer (score 1):

You can split this condition into two like

```
   var elements = array.OrderByDescending(o => o);
   if (put some condition for active where )
         elements= elements.Where(o=>o>2);
```

Answer (score 1):

Query syntax is translated into normal syntax by the compiler, so your example is equivalent to:

```
var elements = array.OrderByDescending(element => element).Where(element => element > 2);
```

Both `OrderByDescending` and `Where` return an `IEnumerable<T>`. What `Where` does is inserting a `Func<T, bool>` as a filter, so when you iterate over the enumerable, it calls that function for each element and skips the element if the function returns false. If you don't have a condition, you can simply leave out the call to `Where`:

```
var elements = array.OrderByDescending(element => element);
```

If, later, you need to select only certain elements, you can apply your filter to elements:

```
elements = elements.Where(element => element > 2);
```

If your filter depends on user input, you can use closures (functions that capture external variables):

```
public Func<int, bool> CreateFilter(int value)
{
    // This returns a function that 'remembers' the given value:
    return element => element > value;
}
```

Which can then be used like:

```
int userInput = 5;
elements = array.OrderByDescending(element => element).Where(CreateFilter(userInput));
```